# Google apps script onchange(e) trigger does not give me correct Active Sheet name when Sorting is performed in one of the sheet tab

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, spreadsheet

```
function onChange(e){
  //sorting in a sheet triggers onChange(e) with e.changeType=='OTHER'
  if(e.changeType()=='OTHER') {
    //Here e.source.getActiveSheet() gives me wrong active sheet.
    //I need to get the activesheet in which sorting is performed
 }
```

Comment: e.changetype is not a function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### This seems to be a bug:

If an [onChange trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/spreadsheet-trigger-builder#onChange()) is fired by the user by [sorting & filtering data](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3540681) (creating a filter, modifying it, sorting, etc.), [SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_spreadsheetapp#getActiveSheet) and [Spreadsheet.getActiveSheet()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_spreadsheet#getActiveSheet) always return the first sheet in the spreadsheet when called in an [onChange trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/spreadsheet-trigger-builder#onChange()) even if that’s not the active sheet.

Other `changeTypes` (`REMOVE_GRID`, `INSERT_ROW`, etc.) return the active sheet.

#### I filed a bug in Issue Tracker:

- [Active sheet cannot be retrieved in onChange triggered by sorting & filtering data](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/183511657)

Anyone affected by this, please consider [subscribing to it by starring it](https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker/guides/subscribe#subscribing_by_starring_an_issue) in order to keep track of it and to help prioritizing it.

Answer (score 1):

You have to limit what pages you want it to execute on.

```
function onMyChange(e) {
  const sh=e.source.getActiveSheet();
  if(sh.getName()=='Your desired sheet name' && e.changeType=="other" ) {
    //put your code here for that page
    //the rest of the pages will not run this code
  }
}
```

Here's what the event object actually looks like:

```
{"authMode":"FULL","changeType":"REMOVE_ROW","source":{},"triggerUid":"a string","user":{"email":"a string","nickname":"a string"}}
```

Comment: e.source.getActiveSheet() always gives the first tab on the sheet when e.changeType=='other'. It does not gives the actual active sheet. That's the problem. Any way around that?