# Switching active sheet after "On Change" trigger

Tags: google-apps-script

So I have an "on change" trigger set to activate this function so that it pulls the name of the tab that has just been created and puts it in a message box. Unfortunately when this is triggered after a new tab has been created it always treats the first tab in the spreadsheet as the active tab (i.e. 'Sheet1). Any ideas on how to to get it to switch the active sheet to the newly created tab?

```
function mynewFunction(e) {
  if (e.changeType == 'INSERT_GRID') {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getName();
    Browser.msgBox(ss);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to figure out a workaround using by combining the use of script Properties, the "On Open" trigger, and the "On Change" trigger!

```
//Gets current list of sheets on open
function onOpened() {
  var currentSheets = new Array();
  var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets();
  for (var i=0 ; i<sheets.length ; i++) currentSheets.push(sheets[i].getName())
  var currentSheets = currentSheets.join();
  var updateProperties = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
  updateProperties.setProperty('sheetsMaster', currentSheets);
}

//Displays name of new sheet on change
function onChanged(e) {
 if (e.changeType == 'INSERT_GRID') {
  var scriptProperties = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperties();
  var sheetsMaster = scriptProperties.sheetsMaster;
  var oldList = sheetsMaster.split(",");
  var newList = new Array();
  var changedSheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets();
  for (var i=0 ; i<changedSheets.length ; i++) newList.push(changedSheets[i].getName())
  for (var i=0 ; i<newList.length ; i++){
    if (newList[i] != oldList[i]) {
      //Displays newly added sheet name
      Browser.msgBox(newList[i]);
      //Updates list to reflect change
      oldList.splice(i,0,newList[i]);
      var setNewProperties = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
      setNewProperties.setProperty('sheetsMaster', oldList.join());
      return;
    }
  }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The last sheet added via UI will be the last one, so you could get it with something like `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets().pop()`.

You could then make it active with [setActiveSheet()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#setactivesheetsheet):

```
function mynewFunction(e) {
  if (e.changeType == 'INSERT_GRID') {
    var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var lastSheet = spreadsheet.getSheets().pop();
    spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(lastSheet);
    Browser.msgBox(spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getName());
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I want the script to work even if a tab in the middle of the spreadsheet is duplicated (i.e. duplicating Sheet3 out of Sheets 1-5).

Comment: It seems that might be a problem in the case of INSERT_GRID and REMOVE_GRID (events of type INSERT_ROW and REMOVE_ROW seem to be working fine though). It looks like it's related to a reported bug (https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/150765301) which is marked as fixed, but apparently it's not. Also related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66782352/3751868